# FTW does not give "newest" directory

Tags: c, posix, traversal, directory

I have the following C code:

```
#include <ftw.h>

#define MAXPATHLEN 100

static time_t createtime = 0;
static char ftwpath[MAXPATHLEN];

[...]

ftw(somepath, get_writedir, 10);
if (ftwpath[0] == '\0') {
    //Code assuming that the directory does not exist.
} else {
    //Some code handeling 
}
```

That is the method that ftw calls:

```
int get_writedir(const char *path, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag)
{
    if (typeflag == FTW_D && sb->st_ctime > createtime) {
        createtime = sb->st_ctime;
        strlcpy(ftwpath, path, MAXPATHLEN);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Generally speking this code works to some extend when typeflag is set to FTW_F, not FTW_D. When I do the latter, nothing happens.
When I do the prior: I do not always get the "newest created directory". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Hm, this should work in general, but you have to note that the ctime is _not_ the _creation time_, as it is often misinterpreted, but the _inode change time_. For a directory, this is for example updated when a file is created or deleted there. The creation time itself is not tracked with commn filesystems

Comment: The problem is also that if I use "/mnt/somedevice/folderinthat" as my rootpath, I sometimes get "/mnt/somedevice/folderinthat/."...

Comment: why is that a problem? Just ignore the entry, when you don't need to process it

Comment: Embarrassing as it is. It turns out, that this just works fine. I made some bus myself in handeling code -.- (wasted my whole morning/noon)...

Comment: happens ;) Don't worry ;)